# HTML - Separação de Buttom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu fiz o seguinte HTML:

```
<p>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>

    <!-- Menu com Submenu -->        
<div class="dropdown">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\Dropdown.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdown-content.js"></script>

  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">teste</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Treinamento 1</a>
    <a href="#">Treinamento 2</a>
    <a href="#">Treinamento 3</a>

    </body>
    </html>
</p>
```

---

JS:

```
/* Quando o usuário clica no botão,
alternar entre ocultar e mostrar o conteúdo suspenso */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Fechar o menu suspenso se o usuário clicar fora dele
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 9px 60px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 05px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

---

Só que eu queria varios botões com a mesma funcionalidade, um abaixo do outro,
e se eu acrescentar mais um, o submenu, abre no primeiro botão,
como faço para separar um botão um do outro, é o id quem define quem é quem?

aí de acordo com a resposta do nosso amigo, eu fiz assim:
não deu certo:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\\10.1.12.10\fabricas\Misael\Rodrigo_Ramos\Toodle\MenuTreinamento\Dropdown.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="\\10.1.12.10\fabricas\Misael\Rodrigo_Ramos\Toodle\MenuTreinamento\dropdown-content.js"></script>

<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">teste1</button><br>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Teste</a>
<a href="#">Treinamento 2</a>

<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">teste2</button><br>
<div id="teste" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Teste</a>
```

mas não deu certo

Comment: Cara vc não pode ter o mesmo ID em mais de um elemento esse é o seu problema com esse script...

Comment: Huuum, imaginei, é que estou testando mas não surtiu resultado... mas vou tentar novamente. valeu

Comment: Eu deixei assim, mas não deu certo:

Comment: se vc for usar código nos comentário vc tem que colocar o código entre essas caracteres ` código aqui ` ai fica assim `<script>`

Comment: <<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">teste1</button><br>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Teste</a>
<a href="#">Treinamento 2</a>

<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">teste2</button><br>
<div id="teste" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Teste</a> >

Comment: Tenho que alterar mais alguma coisa?

Comment: Foi mal, é que to aprendendo sozinho " sem contar com esse tipo de ajuda"

Comment: Eu não tenho muito conhecimento de JS que de para te ajudar, mas logo aparece alguém e te da uma força.

Comment: Cara não sei se é o seu objetivo já que vc está estudando JS, mas se tiver interesse em uma opção só com CSS tipo um drop menu para esses botões me fala que faço um exemplo pra vc.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu fiz um exemplo com jQuery apenas para você ter uma ideia de como irá fazer.
Eu comentei o jQuery para melhor entendimento.

## Lógica usada

1. ao clicar no botão, ele armazena numa variável qual a ***ocorrência*** do botão.
   Exemplo: Tem 3 botões no html. Ao clicar no ***primeiro***, ele armazena ***`1`*** na variável. Ao clicar no ***segundo***, ele armazena ***`2`***. E por aí vai
2. O elemento com a classe ***`dropdown-content`*** de mesma ocorrência recebe (eu dele é retirado) a classe `show`

```js
$(".dropbtn").each(function() { // para cada elemento com a classe dropbtn
  $(this).on("click", function(event) { // quando clicado
    event.stopPropagation(); // previne a ativação de outro click
    var j = $(".dropbtn").index(this); // pega qual a ocorrencia do elemento
    $(".dropdown-content").eq(j).toggleClass("show"); // poe ou tira a classe show de acordo com a ocorrencia do elemento
  });
});

// fechar o dropdown quando clicado em qualquer outro elemento
$(window).click(function() {
  $(".dropdown-content").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 9px 60px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 05px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">teste1</button><br>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Teste</a>
    <a href="#">Treinamento 1</a>
    <button class="dropbtn">teste2</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Teste2</a>
      <a href="#">Treinamento2</a>
      <button class="dropbtn">teste3</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Teste</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```